# Django DRF Field Exists but Serializer does not recognize it

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-admin

I'm getting an `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'description'` for some odd reason. My model is really simple:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    PROFILE = 0
    EVENT_REPORT = 1
    UNIVERSITY_REPORT = 2
    USER_REPORT = 3
    TYPE_LIST = [PROFILE, EVENT_REPORT, UNIVERSITY_REPORT, USER_REPORT]
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (PROFILE, 'Profile'),
        (EVENT_REPORT, 'User Report'),
        (UNIVERSITY_REPORT, 'University Report'),
        (USER_REPORT, 'User Report'),
    )
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type =models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=PROFILE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.description
```

serializer:

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = '__all__'
```

View:

```
class QuestionListView(ListAPIView):
    authentication_classes = (JWTTokenUserAuthentication, TokenAuthentication)
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        takes type paramter. type must be an interger. Types are {}. 
        Returns list of all questions of that type.
        """.format(Question.TYPE_CHOICES)
        types = Question.TYPE_LIST
        try:
            question_type = kwargs['question_type']
            question_type = int(question_type)
            if question_type not in types:
                raise Exception("type must be in {}".format(Question.TYPE_CHOICES))
            questions = Question.objects.filter(type=question_type)
            serializer = QuestionSerializer(questions)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValidationError('Must be an interger.')
        except Exception as e:
            raise e
            raise ValidationError(e)
```

Any idea what I maybe missing? 
I have created objects and they appear fine in the admin view but when I request to list the questions by type I get the error.

```
AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `description` on serializer `QuestionSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'description'.
```

Comment: maybe you should makemigrations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are serializing a **`QuerySet`** object, you should've pass **`many=True`**

```
questions = Question.objects.filter(type=question_type)
serializer = QuestionSerializer(questions, many=true)
```